# What is the best alternative to Cronjob in php?

Tags: php

cron-job can increase server consumption a lot,
I have a PHP script that I want to run every 1 minute. What is the best way not to use Cronjob? I heard that with exec(), Can anyone give me an example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Who said that cronjobs "increase server consumption"? Can you provide a source for that?

Answer (score 1):

Cron itself doesn't use a lot of server cycles. When a server using cron is overloaded, it is due to the jobs it runs.

It's fine to run your php script from cron. But please consider this when you plan to run a php program (or anything) once per minute: make certain it finishes in less than a minute. Because cron will start another one on the next minute whether or not the previous one has finished. That can overload your server.

One way to handle this problem is to have your script ask "am I already running?" right when it starts. If it is already running, the one that just started should simply exit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well, yes, I'm sure it will run in less than a minute, just that there is a solution to do without using cronjob, for example with exec?  @O. Jones

Comment: To have PHP run something with `exec` every minute, you'd need to create a PHP script that is running all the time. Which is basically what `cron` already does. So, why not use what the system provides?